# How can I update a pull request within PyCharm Pro with new changes?

Tags: git, github, pycharm

Let's say I open a pull request, and a reviewer notices that I missed something. After I make the change, how can I add that commit to the same pull request?

I'd like to stay entirely within PyCharm, and ideally without using the CLI.

Thanks!

Comment: Should be enough to push the commit into the branch that is being reviewed.